# get n list items using domcrawler

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle, domcrawler

Is it possible to get only an n number of items using dom crawler ?

I have

```
  `$items = $website->filter('ul.listnews li'); 

   $items>each(function($node,$con){

 }`
```

But I want to get only the first 5 items from the list. I tried running a for loop but I couldn't get it to work. Any ideas on how I could do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` method in chain:

```
$items = $website
         ->filter('ul.listnews li')
         ->reduce(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
             return $i < 5;
          });
```

Comment: Thanks man, I had to remove the Crawler part since I am using Goutte but it's working perfectly. Thanks